# Hackerrank says ~no response on stdout~

Tags: python, stdout

I'm trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem) problem but i keep getting ~no response on stdout~ even though it functions properly with the correct output in visual studio code. The problem specifically asks us to print, and all of the solutions in the comments use the print function for output.

Here is my code :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    students = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        students.append([name,score])
    students.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(1))
    minstd = students[0][1]
    for student in students:
        if student[1] == minstd:
            students.remove(student)

    finallist = []      
    for student in students:
        if student[1] == students[0][1]:
            finallist.append(student[0])
    finallist.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(0))
    print(*finallist, sep = '\n')
```

Thanks in advance.

The issue : as pointed down in a response : the issue was that hackerrank needs you to import operator where as vscode doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just wanna pass the hackerrank
just type this code, i got from discussions, because you didnt set variabel students and operator

```
nested_list = []
scores = []
names = []
if __name__ == '__main__':
for _ in range(int(input())):
name = input()
score = float(input())
nested_list.append([name, score])
scores.append(score)
scores = list(set(scores))
scores.sort()
names = [nested_list[m][0] for m in range(0, len(nested_list)) if nested_list[m][1] == scores[1]]
names.sort()
for name in names:
print(name)`
```

Comment: The issue was indeed operator that wasn't imported

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the definition of 'students' identifier in your code

Comment: I forgot those lines I edited it, but it's not the issue here, I still get the same problem 
When I do a print of students before the sorting it outputs something but not after the sort method. On vscode it works tho